# Setting ReportServerCredentials

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have an asp.net layer between Internet users and ssrs - so no windows authentication. After users login to the site (its an existing site with login, security etc.) on my page I present them a list of reports and try to display them in a ReportViewer control when they select one.

```
rv1 is the reportviewer control.
rv1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
rv1.Visible = true;
rv1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new  Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"]);
rv1.ServerReport.ReportPath = rptPath;

IReportServerCredentials irsc = new MyReportServerCredentials(name, password, domain);
rv1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
```

`MyReportServerCredentials` is class based off `IReportServerCredentials` as specifed elsewhere and MSDN.

When executing the line

```
rv1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
```

gives me `EntryPointNotFoundException`.

**Environment**
SSRS 2008, SQLS 2008 R2, asp.net 3.5., vs2010

edit: the ReportServerUrl points to reporting service, http://localhost:80/ReportServer_SQLS2K8R2

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and found that it was because of a mismatch in versions of the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` assemblies.

In my case my web.config had:

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
     <assemblies>
       ...
       <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
       <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
     </assemblies>
     ...
   </compilation>
   ...
</system.web>
```

and the .aspx page (containing the ReportView control) had:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

But my project was referencing the Version 9.0.0.0 assemblies, I just removed the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` Version 9.0.0.0 reference in my asp.net project and added the Version 10.0.0.0 references. Now the ReportViewer is working fine.

Comment: Hi Joel. Thanks it fixed the issue. Sorry for late reply was away for few days.